# Existential Removal

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

What's the difference between the two statements

$$ 
\forall x \exists y:P(x, y) 
$$

and

$$ 
\forall x: P(x, y)
$$

My understanding the first means $ y $ does not have to be the same for every $ x $, while the second means one $ y $ satisfies $ P $ for every $ x $.

For example, can we write $ \forall n \in Z \exists x \in R : n = x $ as follows

$$
\forall n \in Z (x \in R \, and \, n = x)
$$

Thanks

Comment: For one thing, the second has $y$ as a free variable, the first doesn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first says: "For whatever x you give me, I can always find a y such that the statement is true."

The second says: "For whatever x you give me, the statement is true." In this case, the predicate doesn't depend on y. So you don't need P(x,y); just P(x) is ok.

Comment: This isn't correct.  You can't just ignore the $y$ in the second statement.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $A:=~\forall x\exists y~P(x,y)$ and $B:=~\forall x~P(x,y)$.

The entity $y$ is bound within $A$, where as it occurs free within $B$.

$A$ is claiming that each $x$ has its own $y$ which makes the predicate hold.   That may or not be the same value for each $x$, but there is some such value for each $x$.

$B$ is claiming that each $x$ makes the predictate hold for some *constant* $y$.

---

> For example, can we write $ \forall n \in Z~\exists x \in R : n = x $ as follows
>
> $$\forall n \in Z (x \in R \, and \, n = x)$$

No.   They are not equivalent statements.

The first says that every integer has a real number of equal value.

The second statement says that $x$ is a real number and is simultaneously equal to every integer.